# TwiML with Twilio programable voice not working

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to make a phone call using twilio programmable voice with TwiML. Not sure if I'm doing something completely wrong, but I created an express route to output TwiML

```
router.get('/data', function(req, res) {
  var testXML = builder.create('Response')
   .ele('Say')
   .att('voice', 'alice')
   .txt('You ordered a hamburger')
   .ele('Say')
   .txt('Now this order is complete')
 res.type('text/xml');
 res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
 res.send(testXML.toString());
});
```

This outputs XML as seen below:

[image]

My code to make the phone call is as follows:

```
client.calls
  .create({
url: 'http://XXXXX.com/api/request',
to: '+1XXXXXXXXXX',
from: '+1XXXXXXXXXX',
 })
.then(call => console.log(call.sid))
.done();
```

But twilio keeps outputting Error - 11200 HTTP retrieval failure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed in the REST API call, you are passing a URL with the path:

http://XXXXX.com/api/request

But your Express Route is /data. Also, Twilio uses POST by default, unless you indicate GET in the REST API call.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call (Method)